# Android process in background - it must remain always alive - sometimes it has to play sounds

Tags: android, background, android-service, android-lifecycle

I wrote an Android app that performs voip communication.

During the normal user operations, my app could go in background. 
When it is in background sometimes my app has to receive some voip (and play it in smartphone speaker).

At the moment I implemented the process (that exchanges the signalling messages with the server) by a java runnable class; everything works, but after some time the app is killed (at least I suppose it...) by Android OS and it didn't work anymore.

My target is to get my app always alive, avoiding that Android kill it

An example of what I need is Whatsapp; also while I'm not using it, Whatsapp remains always alive in background and it continues to receive messages (also if it is in background).

I googled a little bit and I saw that may be I have to use an Android Service instead of a runnable java class. I never used it, but before study how to use it I'd like to know if it is the right solution.

Finally, question for StackOverflow experts are:

- How can I keep my app always alive also when it is in background?
- To get this target, is it right to use an Android Service? Or, may be better for me, can I keep my Java
  runnable class    and there is a trick to avoid killing?

Thank you in advance

Comment: When you retrieve the information from the server are you using a service?

Comment: No, at the moment I never used service. As written, the process for exchanging infos from server is implemented by a Java runnable class.

Comment: @stanna ; any suggestion then?

Comment: The app isn't always alive per se. It has a service/listener running, that once it gets a notification, it will notify the user and then they can choose to ignore it or to launch the app (in WhatsApp's example). So services are the way to go. Have a look at this article: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: This question (or similar questions) have been asked millions of times on Stackoverflow. Please search for a suitable answer. Basically, you need to implement a `Service` and there is no guarantee that Android (or the user) will not kill your `Service`. There are some tricks you can use, but these are all described in other questions. It makes no sense to have this discussion again.